# Do I have to add launchimage xcasset in Xamarin?

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, app-store, xamarin-studio, xcasset

I'm having xcasset problems while submitting my Xamarin.IOS application to App Store. That's why, I have deleted my launch image assets in Xamarin Studio but is it a must for properly submitting the application to App Store ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added again launch assets and now it has been published successfully. So it seems its a must.